# MSBuild minify and embed JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC application in Visual Studio 2015 and I'm trying to find a solution to handle minifying and embedding our JavaScript files on a release build. As well, I want to find a similar solution for compiling LESS files and including them as content in a release build. The main caveat here is that in a debug build I want the JavaScript files and LESS files to be delivered as is to make debugging easier.

**Current "Solution"**

Currently the project is setup so that all JS files are set to "Content" as the build action and their minified counterparts are set to "Embedded Resource". To keep these files in sync I'm using the Bundler & Minifier extension. To achieve debug builds using the non-minified files I have a custom `VirtualPathProvider` that checks if the file being requested is a js file and if it exists as a local file, if so it returns the local file otherwise it attempts to get the item from the embedded resource.

Currently there is no solution for handling LESS files.

**Ideal Solution**

Ideally I'd like to include both JS files and LESS files as Content and not have to have their minified/compiled counterparts as part of the project. On a debug build, nothing special happens, the LESS files and JS files are returned as they are. On a release build, the JavaScript files get minified and added as embedded resources and the LESS files get compiled and only the compiled files get included as content.

I know part of this solution will be writing a VirtualPathProvider that on a debug build just returns the files as they are and on build looks for embedded JS files or the compiled LESS files. That part I can handle pretty easily.

My question is, is there a way to minify JS files and embed the minified files only on a release build? And is there a way to compile my LESS files and only include the compiled versions on a release build?

Comment: How about create a target with condition "Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' " to minify JS files? https://www.schaeflein.net/minifying-javascript-files-with-build-events/

Comment: @Leo-MSFT that post has some good information but it doesn't help with embedding the files once they've been minified